# Controls.OfType() generic method call not compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

Consider have this line of code:

```
List<HtmlGenericControl> listOfDivs = 
     this.clientGrid.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>()
                             .ToList<HtmlGenericControl>();
```

The `OfType<>();` isn't recognised, assuming due to a missing `using` directive. I've tried `using System.Web.UI.ControlCollection;`, but that didn't solve the problem.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `OfType<T>`, you need a `using System.Linq;` directive in your code file. This also requires a reference to `System.Core.dll` (referenced in most typical if not all default applications created in Visual Studio 2008+).

Answer (score 3):

Just to add a little to Anthony's answer. if you do a [search on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=OfType&ac=3) for OfType you get the [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) as the first result

It will show you the Namespace and Assembly [image]