# loop through all Charts in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, foreach, charts

I want to access all charts in my Windows Form in a loop, using Visual Studio C# 2013. I have a bunch of them in the form and i want to iteratively add new series to them, depending on the chart.name

what i've tried is to use the foreach loop and controls.OfType to loop through them. But the compiler is giving me an error.

```
        foreach (Chart tempchart in this.Controls.OfType<Chart>)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(tempchart.Name);
        }
```

> Error:
>   Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?*

What am i doing wrong here? I've tried to search for Chart collections etc. but am flooded with answers about how to add data collections and series collections to a chart.

Comment: Could you create a list variable first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102135/controls-oftype-generic-method-call-not-compiling has an example of that if you want it.

Comment: Did any of you read the error message? It is very clear and the solution is straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to loop on the method itself and not on the method result.

```
var method = this.Controls.OfType<Chart>;
var methodResult = this.Controls.OfType<Chart>();
```

You only miss the `()` at the end that will **invoke** the method.

```
foreach ( Chart tempchart in this.Controls.OfType<Chart>() )
{
  MessageBox.Show( tempchart.Name );
}
```